# Post duplicated in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm desperated. I have a blog with random post but in second and next pages, show some post duplicated.

This is the code of index.php

```
<?php global $query_string;

query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=rand' ); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

         <div class="post-content">

 //Content erased                                  

             <?php if($data['post_meta']): ?>

             <?php endif; ?>

         </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php themefusion_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2); ?>

</div>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Anybody have a solution for not repeat post? Really thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the relevant code.